# Javascript calculate delivery date

Tags: javascript

I have complicating problem. I have a website that shows how many days it is for the product delivery. But I need to change that the javascript not showing days, but the exact date when will be the delivery.

Here is an image of how it looks like now

[image]

Here is some part of the original code:

```
function getProductRecordHTML(Product)
{
    var manufacturer = "", article_show = "", name = "";
                
    var time_to_exe = Product.time_to_exe;
    

    if(time_to_exe >= 6)
    {
        time_to_exe = time_to_exe + " days";
    }
```

This one `time_to_exe` shows the number of days which you can  see on the image

As I have a different amount of days for delivery, here is the result of what I need:

If orders are ordered till 12 pm

All products which have 1-day delivery, then this day replacing with next working day date

All products which have 2-days delivery, then this day replacing with the working day after tomorrow date

etc... this continues till 5 days delivery.

When it's showing 6 days delivery, then it's should look like this:

Order need to make from Monday to Thursday 12 pm, to get delivery on next Monday, so 6 days on website replacing with next Monday date

```
Example: If you order on Thursday 19/08/2021 till 12 PM then delivery will be on 23/08/2021, but if you will order on Friday 20/08/21 or any day till next Monday, then delivery will be on 30/08/2021
```

When it's showing 7 days delivery, then it's should look like this:

Order need to make from Monday to Wednesday 12 pm, to get delivery on next Monday, so 7 days on website replacing with next Monday date

```
Example: If you order on Wednesday 18/08/2021 till 12 PM then delivery will be on 23/08/2021, but if you will order on Thursday 19/08/21 or any day till next Monday, then delivery will be on 30/08/2021
```

When it's showing 8, 9, and 10 days delivery, then it's should look like this:

Order need to make from Monday to Wednesday 12 pm, to get delivery on next Monday after week, so 8, 9,and  10 days on website replacing with next Monday date after a week

```
Example: If you order on Wednesday 18/08/2021 till 12 PM then delivery will be on 30/08/2021, but if you will order on Thursday 19/08/21 or any day till next Monday, then delivery will be on 06/09/2021
```

When it's showing 15 and 18 days delivery, then it's should look like this:

Order need to make from Monday to Wednesday 12 pm, to get delivery on next Monday after week, so 15 and 18 days on website replacing with closest Monday after 3 weeks

```
Example: If you order Wednesday 18/08/2021 till 12 PM then delivery will be on 13/09/2021, but if you will order on Thursday 19/08/21 or any day till next Monday, then delivery will be on 20/09/2021
```

When it's showing 33 days delivery, then it's should look like this:

The order needs to make from Monday to Wednesday at 12 pm, to get delivery on Monday after 33 days, so 33 days on website replacing with a date after 33 days from today.

I know, this is so complicated, but I hope someone understands me and will try to help me.

P.S. I was trying to add these dates, but only what I could do was just add delivery days to the current date, and it was like this (this is a format, how it should be looking, after all, ):

[image]

Comment: So far this looks like a list of business requirements. What it the question?

Comment: @udalmik The question is, how to do that in real life, as I mentioned in my question, how to calculate a delivery date, please check the examples. I'm sorry if the question was not understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a date displayed instead of days remaining you have to generate a new Date object and add the amount of days to it. This can be done with `const date = new Date()`, after this you can easily modify the date objects value using `date.setDate(date.getDate() + amountOfDaysRemaings)`.

Based on your example, all you have to do is:

```js
    var displayDate;
    if(time_to_exe >= 6)
    {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(time_to_exe));
        displayDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
    if (displayDate) {
      // put displayDate into the cell 
    } else {
      // put `${time_to_exec} days` into the cell 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have too little knowledge, that's why I asked a question. I do not understand how to modify the date object. Can you please give some examples?

Comment: I used a part from your code snippet. The variable `displayDate` is filled with a string based on your locale settings and will return the date. The `if` at the end is to show, how to use that var later in the script. Somewhere the var `time_to_exec` is stored inside the document, i don't know where, your example is to short. -- At this point, where you normally put `time_to_exec` into the document, you have to use the if and display `displayDate` if it is not empty/undefined, otherwise display the `time_to_exec + 'days';`.